# How to convert delay to millis

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I have a simple code with delays.
I'd like to know how to convert this code to millis? Is there a function to do so?

```
long revers = 1000;

void setup() {
  pinMode(D1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);    
}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(D1, LOW);
  delay(revers);               
  digitalWrite(D2, HIGH);  
  delay(revers);
  digitalWrite(D2, LOW);
  delay(revers);
  digitalWrite(D1, HIGH);
  delay(revers);

}
```

Comment: Standard c++ doesn't have a `millis()` function. I retagged your question, that must be something arduino specific.

Comment: `millis()` returns the number of milliseconds since startup, `delay()` waits for the given amount of time - they perform different actions, so "converting" between them doesn't make much sense... You can _use_ `millis()` to implement some kind of delay, but what problem are you trying to solve? Do you want a busy wait like `delay`? Then just use `delay()`. Or you want change your code to be a state machine, which is called often and performs the different tasks when the time is right, returning immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept is this: record the millis() at a given moment in a variable - say 'starttime'. Now, during every loop(), check the time that has elapsed by subtracting millis() from 'starttime'. If the elapsed time is greater than the delaytime you set, execute code. Reset the starttime to create a repeating pattern.

That may be too short of an explanation for you, so before you dive into the code, I highly advise you to read this introduction about [using millis() for timing](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=503368.0). It's lengthy, but it explains the principle extensively. This will help you understand the code below.

Lastly, there are several libraries written to make the use of timing easier. For instance the [SimpleTimer](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer)-library, but you can google "arduino timer library" for others. I've included an example below.

1 second on, 3 seconds off:

```
unsigned long startMillis;  //some global variables available anywhere in the program
unsigned long currentMillis;
const unsigned long period = 1000;  //the value is a number of milliseconds
int fase; //value used to determine what action to perform


void setup() {
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);    
  startMillis = millis();  //initial start time
  fase = 0;
}



void loop() {
  currentMillis = millis();  //get the current "time" (actually the number of milliseconds since the program started)
  if (currentMillis - startMillis >= period)  //test whether the period has elapsed
  {
    if (fase == 0)
    {
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
      startMillis = currentMillis;  //IMPORTANT to save the start time of the current LED state.
      fase = 1; //increment fase, so next action will be different
    }
    else if (fase == 1)
    {               
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);  
      startMillis = currentMillis; 
      fase = 2;
    }
    else if (fase == 2)
    {
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);
      startMillis = currentMillis; 
      fase = 3;
    }
    else if (fase == 3)
    {
      digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
      fase = 0;
      startMillis = currentMillis; 
    }
  }
}
```

Example of a flashing led using the SimpleTimer library

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

// the timer object
SimpleTimer timer;
int ledPin = 13; 

// a function to be executed periodically
void repeatMe() {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, !digitalRead(ledPin));
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    timer.setInterval(1000, repeatMe);
}

void loop() {
    timer.run();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Yes, I mean 1 second on, 3 seconds off on each led. Your code doesn't work I repair it and I add ELSE IF in each fase. But is a problem with timing. I don't know why when I set 1000 ms this is not 1000 ms but about 6000 ms. Do you know why?

Comment: I updated my answer a bit and tested the code on my arduino. The current code works for me and does: LED1 on (1sec) LED1  off (1sec) LED2 on (1sec) LED2 off (1 sec). So it's a 4 second loop. Please try it, and if the timing is not what you want, add a step by step schema.

Comment: Yes, your code is ok and working exactly like I want. But can you check my arduino code and see what is wrong there? https://github.com/phaterster/ZPI/blob/master/projekcik%202.ino There is like I said before. When I set 1000 ms, then its working like 6000 ms. I don;t know why. I am setting lights frequency by website.

Comment: I don't see anything yet. But there is a lot going on. You could try `println(millis() - currentMillis)` at several points in your loop, this might reveal where the time in you program is spend